# why i can not create event in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create event for one of my database using below code,

```
use testing;

show events;

show warnings;

set global event_scheduler =on;

DELIMITER $$

create event table_backup_testingTo_test on schedule every 1 day 
starts '2015-10-14 16:40:00'
do
select * into test.event_table_testing from testing.manitest;

DELIMITER $$
```

After run this code if i check in **show events** then there is no event in the name of **table_backup_testingTo_test**

where am i doing mistake?

Note : I am using mysql workbench 6.3

Comment: Can you pls paste the error message you get?

Comment: @Shadow I dont get any error.it shows " set global event_scheduler=on   0 row(s) affected.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the following query: `select * into test.event_table_testing from testing.manitest;`?

Answer (score 0):

You change the delimiter, but actually never finish a statement with it. And after the multiple statements you should change the delimiter back to default. In your case you don't need a delimiter at all, since it's just one statement. Try like this:

```
DELIMITER ; /*assuming it's still set to $$*/
use testing;

show events;

show warnings;

set global event_scheduler =on;
create event table_backup_testingTo_test on schedule every 1 day 
starts '2015-10-14 16:40:00'
do
select * into test.event_table_testing from testing.manitest;
```

Or, if you have multiple statements in your event:

```
use testing;

show events;

show warnings;

set global event_scheduler =on;

DELIMITER $$

create event table_backup_testingTo_test on schedule every 1 day 
starts '2015-10-14 16:40:00'
do
begin
select * into test.event_table_testing from testing.manitest;
select 'we have multiple statements here';
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

My test:

```sql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE `testing`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `testing`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `manitest` (
    ->   `column_0` int,
    ->   `column_1` varchar(7),
    ->   `column_2` varchar(55)
    -> );

mysql> INSERT INTO `manitest`
    -> (`column_0`, `column_1`, `column_2`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, 'value_1_0', 'value_2_0'),
    -> (2, 'value_1_1', 'value_2_1'),
    -> (3, 'value_1_2', 'value_2_2');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE DATABASE `test`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE `event_table_testing` (
    ->   `column_0` int,
    ->   `column_1` varchar(7),
    ->   `column_2` varchar(55)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * INTO `test`.`event_table_testing`
    -> FROM `testing`.`manitest`;
ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: test

mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`event_table_testing`
    -> SELECT * FROM `testing`.`manitest`;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE EVENT `table_backup_testingTo_test` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    -> STARTS '2015-10-14 16:40:00'
    -> DO
    -> -- select * into test.event_table_testing from testing.manitest;
    -> INSERT INTO `test`.`event_table_testing`
    -> SELECT * FROM `testing`.`manitest`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW EVENTS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: test
                Name: table_backup_testingTo_test
                .
                .
                .
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```